# How to convert 2D string list to 2D int list python?

Tags: python, string, list, int, type-conversion

How to convert a 2d string list in 2d int list? example:

```
>>> pin_configuration = [['1', ' 1', ' 3'], ['2', ' 3', ' 5'], ['3'], ['4', ' 5'], ['5', ' 1'], ['6', ' 6'], ['7']]

>>> to [[1,1,3], [2,3,5], [3], [4,5], [5,1], [6,6], [7]]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python 3.x

```
print ( [list( map(int,i) ) for i in l] )
```

Output :

```
[[1, 1, 3], [2, 3, 5], [3], [4, 5], [5, 1], [6, 6], [7]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Do with list comprehension,

```
In [24]: l =  [['1', ' 1', ' 3'], ['2', ' 3', ' 5'], ['3'], ['4', ' 5'], ['5', ' 1'], ['6', ' 6'], ['7']]

In [25]: result = [map(int,i) for i in l]
```

Result

```
In [26]: print result
[[1, 1, 3], [2, 3, 5], [3], [4, 5], [5, 1], [6, 6], [7]]
```

Comment: this is Python 2 only. Cast to `list` to be cross-version

Comment: @Ev.Kounis OP doesn't mentioned any version. And the functionality part will work with both.

Comment: Whenever no version is mentioned and one **has** to be assumed, going with the latest is the safest bet imho. But covering both is rather trivial in this case.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis So i used `2.7` here. I guess it's pretty stable and safest.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a function called int() that will make strings into integers. Try that out.